# Do I need 5 separate disconnects for my 9k btu 5 zone mini split?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, switch, mini-split

I’m installing a 5 zone 9k btu mini split and I’m not sure where to start with the wiring. Looked in the manual there’s a few different ways. I was hoping to use one box for my upstairs units (2) put the disconnect in central location. And hopefully the same with the two on the first level and I plan to put one in the basement which I assume would be good to wire straight into my box. More than likely going to hire a professional but id like to at least give it a try. Thanks for the information!!

Comment: NEC 110.3(B) Must be installed according to instructions and labeling. *What do the instructions say?* You won't be able to put refrigerant in it anyway due to Federal rules, but you can certainly inform yourself and make sure electrical is where it needs to be. *The Vast* majority of mini-splits require only electrical at the outdoor unit, and they feed power from there to the head units.  The head units only power a fan, so that might even be just 24V.

Answer (score 2):

5 **zone** minisplit probably needs ONE disconnect, in line of sight and less than 25(?) feet from the outside unit (which I assume there is one of, as you did not say 5 separate mini-splits, one for each zone.)

Inside head units don't need a disconnect, anywhere I know of.

Comment: New Hampshire requires disconnects on the indoor units. Strange but true. See my accompanying answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say where you live, but in New Hampshire the chief electrical inspector for the state ruled in 2015 based on NEC 2014 that each indoor unit needs its own disconnect so that it may be serviced safely. The outdoor disconnect for the outdoor unit, which supplies power to all parts of the system, is not in line of sight of the indoor units so it does not qualify as a disconnect for them.

A disconnect may be mounted on the wall near the indoor unit or an in-line touch-safe plug (similar to a luminaire disconnect) may be installed in the wiring box within the case of the indoor unit. The only inline plug that was approved as of 2015 was the [Ideal 103G](https://www.idealind.com/us/en/shop/product-type/connectors/luminaire-disconnects/powerplug/powerplugr-luminaire-disconnect-model-103g-3-wire-male-box-of-2-000-30-103gm.html). This plug is UL listed for NEC 410.130G compliance, which has nothing to do with air conditioners, but that was how the chief inspector ruled.

Comment: In which case you'll need **6** disconnects. Oy. New Hampster does like the beat of their own drummer sometimes...

Comment: I’m in Pennsylvania